# Selenium IDE : Not able to automate click event on button

Tags: selenium, ide, mouseclick-event

Not able to automate click event on button. the Button details are :

```html
<input id="ctl01_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcInvoice_tpInvoiceDetails_btnSave" class="button" type="submit" onclick="javascript:return disableit();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl01$ContentPlaceHolder1$tcInvoice$tpInvoiceDetails$btnSave", "", true, "vgInvoice", "", false, false))" value="Create Invoice" name="ctl01$ContentPlaceHolder1$tcInvoice$tpInvoiceDetails$btnSave">
```

Please advise

Comment: use this xpath:  //input[@class='button"] . If you have multiple input tag's with same className then that will identify more than one element. So make sure that xpath for that element is Unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Selenese syntax but from a quick look you could try something like:

```
clickAndWait | id=ctl01_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcInvoice_tpInvoiceDetails_btnSave
```

Alternatively you could try using the xpath locator:

```
clickAndWait | xpath=//input[@value='Create Invoice']
```